Unable to assign a permission set with specific system permissions to user with Salesforce License
A permission set(session based) is created (without license). It has some permissions including system permissions(Freeze users, Manage dev sandboxes, Monitor Login History), when this permission set is assigned to user(with Salesforce license), getting error message.
"Can't assign permission set to user. The user license doesn't allow the permission. Freeze users/Manage Dev Sanboxes/Login History"**

 


The error simply means the permission set you are trying to assign has some permissions that requires assigning a Permission Set License to it.
The permission set might need a Proper Salesforce License attached to it.

Hi @Mohith Shrivastava, thanks for your response. But when I tried to replicate the same in personal dev org, am able to assign the permission set (without license) to user.

Your Developer org user might have permissions needed already available via other permission sets so it is a non issue.

okay, thank you.
